# What does the intersection of two function types boil down to?

Tags: flowtype

Can someone point me to a comprehensive guide on the theory behind flowtype function intersections? Behavior is confusing to me. I understand that this type:

```
type FnT = ((string) => string) & ((number) => string);
```

reduces down to `(string | number) => (string & string)`, but why is is that i can't cast the parameter to either `string` or `number` ???
i.e `const g: FnT = (p: string) => { return "hi"; }` gives me
`Cannot assign function to`g`because  string [1] is incompatible with  number [2] in the first argument.`.

Why??? isn't `string` a perfectly valid subtype of `string | number`?

is this because it expects a super type?

if this is the case then why is it that a union of same two function types lets me cast the param to one or the other?

i.e.
`const FnT = ((string) => string) | ((number) => string)` works with
`const g: FnT = (p: string) => ("hi")` ??? wouldn't we expect a supertype of `string | number` here?

Comment: can you, please, add flow try (https://flow.org/try/) example link here, to illustrate what exactly problem are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

With flow, you need to test all alternative types before casting.

example, if your type is `string|number`, and you want to cast as a number, you must first test that it is not actually a string.

This is because Flow will not try and modify your values for you, it is only a type checker. You must modify your values yourself, meaning flow can not 'convert' a number to a string, it can only cast the *type*.